# Python: Selenium Webdriver Wait EC

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to get data only after the page has been *completely* loaded; as in after the favicon turns from waiting to site's own icon. The source from where I am trying to get data from gives me 3 tables, these tables have same html so the same xpaths, i tried using:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "someclass_name")))
```

But this condition passes as soon as either table is loaded and so my script declares the other two arrays for those tables to be 'None'. Also i tried using 'EC.staleness_of' which didnt work as it passes as soon the another page is loaded i.e; as soon as the page is refreshed. I want a way by which the condition passes only after everything is loaded, not that a particular element is located.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code to wait until all 3 tables appears in `DOM`

```
WebDriverWait(driver,timeout).until(lambda: len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("someclass_name")) == 3)
```

Comment: Great! How about a more general case? For example; the page actually returns at most 3 tables, more like if the elements are dynamic what would be the best way?

Comment: @Andersson Is `lambda` supported by Python 3.6.1 on Windows as well? Can you please refer me some documentations on the usage and implementation of `lambda`? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB, Yes, anonymous functions are supported by 3.6.1 version. You can get some description [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)